# Keep consistent dtype and timezone when concatenating with NaT in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, timezone

I have two pandas DataFrames containing time series that must be concatenated for further processing. One DataFrame contains localized timestamps while the other contains `NaT` in the time column. When concatenating, the column type changes from `datetime64[ns]` to `object`, hindering the further analysis.

**My goal**: keeping a localized time column, even after concatenation with `NaT`.

#### Example code

```py
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'DateTime': pd.date_range(
            start='2022-10-10',
            periods=7,
            freq='1D',
            tz='America/New_York'
        ),
        'Value': range(7)
    }
)
b = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'DateTime': pd.NaT,
        'Value': range(10,20),
    }
)
c = pd.concat([a, b], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

The dtypes of `a` and `b` are different:

```py
>>> print(a.dtypes)
DateTime    datetime64[ns, America/New_York]
Value                                  int64
dtype: object

>>> print(b.dtypes)
DateTime    datetime64[ns]
Value                int64
dtype: object
```

Since the timestamp for `a` is localized but the timestamp for `b` is not, the concatenation results in an `object`.

```py
>>> print(c.dtypes)
DateTime    object
Value        int64
dtype: object
```

When trying to localize `b`, I get a `TypeError`:

```py
>>> b['DateTime'] = b['DateTime'].tz_localize('America/New_York')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/so-pandas-nat.py", line 27, in <module>
    b['DateTime'] = b['DateTime'].tz_localize('America/New_York')
  File ".venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 9977, in tz_localize
    ax = _tz_localize(ax, tz, ambiguous, nonexistent)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 9959, in _tz_localize
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: index is not a valid DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.tz_localize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_localize.html) for processing column, if use [`Series.tz_localize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tz_localize.html) it want processing `DatetimeIndex`, here raise error, becuse `RangeIndex`:

```
b['DateTime'] = b['DateTime'].dt.tz_localize('America/New_York')
c = pd.concat([a, b], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

print(c.dtypes)
DateTime    datetime64[ns, America/New_York]
Value                                  int64
dtype: object
```